# JSF datatable color a row based on condition

Tags: jsf, datatable

I want to color a row of a datatable if the country column's text is 'UK'. Here is my XHTML file:

```
 <h:dataTable value="#{personBean.persons}" var="p" 
    rowStyleClass="#{p.country eq 'UK' ? 'colored' : null}">
            
       <h:column >
            <f:facet name="header">Country</f:facet>
             "#{p.country}"
      </h:column>
 </h:dataTable>
```

Here is my CSS file:

```
.colored {
   background-color: #cceeff;
   color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I can't achieve that a row is colored.

Comment: Its working for me.  Check in the chrome console whether CSS file is linked properly to your page and clear the catch then try again. also remove the double quote from `"#{p.country}"` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Native JSF `h:dataTable` will not be evaluate `rowStyleClass` on per row basis.

It will happen in Primefaces `p:dataTable`.

One alternative you can do is you have build a `String` of comma separated style classes at your `ManagedBean` and supply it to `rowStyleClass` attribute.

For Example:
ManagedBean:

```
String rowStyles;
public void getRowStyles(){
    for(Person p: persons){
      rowStyles+=p.getCountry().equals("UK") ? "colored," : ",";
    }

    return rowStyles;
}
```

XHTML:

```
<h:dataTable rowStyleClass="#{personBean.rowStyles}" ...>
```